# How Do I Silence Bixby Vision?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-8

Whenever I use Bixby Vision to scan a QR code or do other things, it makes a loud chime. This occurs even when my phone is in vibrate-only mode, and my media volume is muted.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

Bixby has independent volume settings.

[image: bixby volume]